# Will monit restart delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job, monit

If my `delayed_job` server broke then will `monit` automatically restart the `delayed_job` server?

Comment: Only if you've configured it to do so.

Comment: This question would best be asked on serverfault.

Comment: how to check that monit has started a delayed_job or not?

Answer (score 2):

You have to tell monit to do this... I use the following config:

```
check process delayed_job with pidfile /srv/rails/restorm_com/current/tmp/pids/delayed_job.pid
  start program = "/bin/su -c 'RAILS_ENV=production /srv/rails/restorm_com/current/script/delayed_job start' rails"
  stop program  = "/bin/su -c 'RAILS_ENV=production /srv/rails/restorm_com/current/script/delayed_job stop' rails"

  if cpu > 80% for 3 cycles then alert
  if loadavg(5min) greater than 2 for 3 cycles then alert
```

Comment: how to check that monit has started a delayed_job or not?

Comment: "monit status" shows you a summary of all monit-watched stuff... There you'll see if delayed job is started or not